# Add a new Kafka Node to an Existing Kafka Cluster without downtime

Tags: apache-kafka

I have a 3 node Kafka cluster with a single zookeeper node, my question is how can I add a new Kafka node to this cluster without downtime?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just add it. There's no need to restart anything else

Comment: I mean I have a single zookeeper node for each Kafka node. Does it effect?

Comment: You should not have one Zookeeper per Kafka broker, no. But you should have more than one for fault tolerance

Answer (score 0):

Adding servers to a Kafka cluster is easy, just assign them a unique broker ID and start up Kafka on your new servers. However these new servers will not automatically be assigned any data partitions, so unless partitions are moved to them they won’t be doing any work until new topics are created. So usually when you add machines to your cluster you will want to migrate some existing data to these machines. Other common reasons for migrating data are decommissioning of brokers and rebalancing data across the cluster (when it becomes unbalanced).

found this from [here](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/kafka/post-deployment.html)